# PHP Apache rewrite 500 error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am creating a simple PHP web app. I am using the following .htaccess:

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

To use the URL:
localhost/Webshop/ 
localhost/Webshop/Pagename

In the index file I am getting the Request_URI for showing the right page.

Now, the problem is, when I try the following:

localhost/Webshop/Category/1

I am getting an 500 rewrite error.

It's because I think the server can't handle the second part of the url (so the second /)

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, with this code nothing works anymore. Everything gives 500 now.

Comment: Have you enabled `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: What does the error log say? Check that then try my edit too.

Comment: this is my htaccess error: 
[Thu Feb 05 14:56:08.882164 2015] [core:error] [pid 14380:tid 1752] [client ::1:59109] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

your htaccess:
[Thu Feb 05 14:56:17.530610 2015] [core:alert] [pid 14380:tid 1728] [client ::1:59110] C:/xampp/htdocs/Webshop/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: Awesome, great it worked. You can thank me by upvoting the answer ;)